# Implementation of the graph through the adjacent vertices

Tags: c++, graph

Implementation of the graph through the adjacent vertices
Good day. I have a task-write function for the graph through the adjacent vertices - add a vertex, add the edge, add the weight of the edge.
Remove vertex, remove edge, remove edge weight
Find adjacent or ribs.
I wrote what I knew, but where are the signs - "??????" there I do not know how to do, so I want to ask you for help

//header//

```
     #pragma once
     #include <vector>
     struct Edge 
     {
        int mV; 
        int mW;
      };

      struct Node
      { 
         int mEnd; 
         float mWeight; 
      };

      using AjacencyList = std::vector<Node>;
      class Graph
      {
           public:
           Graph(int key, bool digraph);
           void insert(int key);
           void insertEdge(Edge edge);
           void remove(int key);
           void removeEdge(Edge edge);
           bool relatedEdge(Edge edge1, Edge edge2);
           bool directed();

           private:
               bool mDigraph = false;
               AjacencyList mAdjacencyLists;
           };
```

//cpp//

```
           #include "stdafx.h"
           #include "Graph.h"
           #include <iostream>

           Graph::Graph(int key, bool digraph)
           : mDigraph(digraph)
           , mAdjacencyLists(key)
           {
           }

           void Graph::insert(int key)
           { 
               if (mAdjacencyLists[key].mEnd == false)
                     mAdjacencyLists[key].mEnd = true;
               else
                     std::cout << "Sorry" << "\n";
           }

           void Graph::insertEdge(Edge edge)
           {
              if ((mAdjacencyLists[edge.mV].mEnd == true) && 
                 (mAdjacencyLists[edge.mW].mEnd == true) 
                  && (mAdjacencyLists[edge.mV].mWeight == false) && 
                  (mAdjacencyLists[edge.mW].mEnd == false) && (edge.mV != 
                   edge.mW))
              {
                    Node node;
                    mAdjacencyLists[edge.mV] = node.mEnd; // ???
                    mAdjacencyLists[edge.mW] = node.mWeight; //???

              }
           }

           void Graph::remove(int key)
           {
                if (mAdjacencyLists[key].mEnd == true)
                {
                    mAdjacencyLists[key].mEnd = false;
                    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; ++i)
                    {
                        if (mAdjacencyLists[i].mEnd == 1)
                              --mEnd; // ????????
                    }
                }
                else
                    std::cout << "Error" <<"\n";
            }

            void Graph::removeEdge(Edge edge)
            {
                 if ((mAdjacencyLists[edge.mV].mEnd == true) && 
                     (mAdjacencyLists[edge.mW].mEnd == true) && 
                      (mAdjacencyLists[edge.mV].mWeight == true) 
                        && (mAdjacencyLists[edge.mW].mEnd == true) && 
                      (edge.mV != edge.mW))
                 {
                    // ???

                 }
            }

            bool Graph::relatedEdge(Edge edge1, Edge edge2)
            {
               if (edge1.mW == edge2.mW)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }

            bool Graph::directed()
            {
               return mDigraph;
            }
```

Comment: At least 4 indirect questions in one post. Maybe it is needed a little decomposition? I mean, deal with each question in order. This would be really helpful to you to understand the task clearly.

Comment: @SmitYcyken https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424340/add-and-subtract-the-edges-in-the-graph-through-the-list-of-adjacent-vertices?noredirect=1#comment85850498_49424340