# add and subtract the edges in the graph through the list of adjacent vertices

Tags: c++, graph

Implementation of the graph through the adjacent vertices
Good day. I have a task-write function for the graph through the adjacent add edge
Remove the edge

But I do not know how to implement it. Need your help.

```
 struct Edge 
 {
   int mV; 
   int mW;
   float mWeight;
 };

 struct Node
 { 
  int mEnd; 
  float mWeight; 
 };

 using AdjacencyList = std::vector<Node>;
 using VertexList = std::vector<AdjacencyList>;
 class Graph
 {
   public:
   bool addEdge(const Edge& edge);
   bool removeEdge(const Edge& edge);
   private:
    VertexList mVertexList;
 };

 bool Graph::addEdge(const Edge& edge)
 {
if ((mAdjacencyLists[edge.mV].mEnd == true) && (mAdjacencyLists[edge.mW].mEnd == true) 
    && (mAdjacencyLists[edge.mV].mWeight == false) && (mAdjacencyLists[edge.mW].mEnd == false) && (edge.mV != edge.mW))
{
    Node node;
    mAdjacencyLists[edge.mV] = node.mEnd; // ???
    mAdjacencyLists[edge.mW] = node.mWeight; //???

}
}

 bool Graph::removeEdge(const Edge& edge)
 {
  if ((mAdjacencyLists[edge.mV].mEnd == true) && (mAdjacencyLists    [edge.mW].mEnd == true) && (mAdjacencyLists[edge.mV].mWeight == true) 
    && (mAdjacencyLists[edge.mW].mEnd == true) && (edge.mV != edge.mW))
   {
    // ???

    }
```

}

UPD(rewritten the code):

```
 bool Graph::addEdge(const Edge& edge)
 {
  mVertexList[edge.mV].push_back({ edge.mW, edge.mWeight });
  mVertexList[edge.mW].push_back({ edge.mV, edge.mWeight });
 }

 bool Graph::removeEdge(const Edge& edge)
 {
   auto ita = find_if(mVertexList[edge.mV].cbegin(), mVertexList  [edge.mV].cend(), [edge.mW](const Node& n) { return n.mEnd == edge.mW; });
   mVertexList[edge.mV].erase(ita);
   auto itb = find_if(mVertexList[edge.mW].cbegin(), mVertexList[edge.mW].cend(), [edge.mV](const Node& n) { return n.mEnd == edge.mV; });
   mVertexList[edge.mW].erase(itb);
 }
```

Comment: Привіт! What information do you need to store apart from connectivity? Edge weights? Something else?

Comment: @Yola I just need to write functions that add and remove edges through the list of adjacent vertices. I think add to the vector VertexList

Comment: I don't understand this condition `mAdjacencyLists[edge.mV].mEnd == true`. you test that `mEnd` is not zero? Why?

Comment: @Yola Привіт) the next vertex is not zero
but if you did? I just wrote as I knew, I guess I really wrote gaggle)))

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422595/implementation-of-the-graph-through-the-adjacent-vertices

Answer (score 0):

In this example i expect that you know number of vertices in the graph in forward.

```
class G {
    struct Neighbour{
        int _end;
        int _weight;
    };

    std::vector<std::list<Neighbour>> adj;

public:
    G(int verticesCount) : adj(verticesCount) {}

    void addEdge(int a, int b, int w) {
        assert(!hasEdge(a, b));
        adj[a].push_back({ b, w });
        adj[b].push_back({ a, w });
    }

    void dropEdge(int a, int b) {
        assert(hasEdge(a, b));
        auto ita = find_if(adj[a].cbegin(), adj[a].cend(), [b](const Neighbour& n) { return n._end == b; });
        adj[a].erase(ita);
        auto itb = find_if(adj[b].cbegin(), adj[b].cend(), [a](const Neighbour& n) { return n._end == a; });
        adj[b].erase(itb);
    }

    bool hasEdge(int a, int b) {
        auto it = find_if(adj[a].cbegin(), adj[a].cend(), [b](const Neighbour& n) { return n._end == b; });
        // here you might want to check if adjacency list for b also contains entry for the edge
        return it != adj[a].cend();
    }

    int edgeWeight(int a, int b) {
        auto it = find_if(adj[a].cbegin(), adj[a].cend(), [b](const Neighbour& n) { return n._end == b; });
        // the same as in hasEdge, some consistency check might be needed
        return it->_weight;
    }
};

void testG() {
    G g(4);

    g.addEdge(0, 1, 10);
    g.addEdge(1, 2, 20);
    g.addEdge(2, 3, 30);

    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << g.hasEdge(0, 1) << " w = " << g.edgeWeight(0, 1) << endl;
    cout << g.hasEdge(1, 2) << " w = " << g.edgeWeight(1, 2) << endl;
    cout << g.hasEdge(2, 3) << " w = " << g.edgeWeight(2, 3) << endl;
    g.dropEdge(1, 2);
    cout << g.hasEdge(1, 2) << endl;
}


int main() {
    testG();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

> true w = 10
>   true w = 20
>   true w = 30
>   false

Storing graph with adjacency list representation leads to some information duplication, so it is good to have consistency checks.

Comment: which means "{}" in push_back?

Comment: @OxanaVolynets see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) #7

Comment: I have missed the check so far, here is a code I got out of it(UPD) but it screams on [edge.mW] and [edge.mV]. I do something wrong?

Comment: @OxanaVolynets maybe you forgot to initialize `mVertexList` and it has 0 elements.

Comment: syntax error: missing ']' before '.'                                                            '.': skipping unexpected token(s) before lambda body

Comment: @OxanaVolynets try `int mv = edge.mV;` and then pass `mv` to the lambda.

Comment: Thanks for helping you do the task for the lab

Comment: @OxanaVolynets if it helped to solve your problem you can check the acceptance tick ;) Also i invite you to visit https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/ one day in case you will have questions about Ukrainian language.

Comment: Could you take a look at my code again? in the visual  studio crept. via online campiler is working. and I do not understand what is wrong (( https://ideone.com/QljM0i

Comment: @OxanaVolynets you don't initialize mVertexList, you should initialize it probably in constructor of Graph class.

Comment: Graph::Graph(int key)
 : mVertexList(key)
{
}  all the same, to crush ((

Comment: @OxanaVolynets I added this single line `Graph() : mVertexList(4) {}` and it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the issue

Comment: I thought, in my Graph class, only int values were written to the graph. And if I for example want string, float. How to write a template so that it is like for all types. in list use or vector? You understand the graphs, maybe there is an idea?

Comment: @OxanaVolynets you need to create a separate question for this. You should explain your current design without unrelated details.